# Build Logistic Regression Model for shares

Tags: r, logistic-regression, non-linear-regression

The data i am working with , contains the closing prices of 10 shares of the S&P 500 index.

Data :

```
> dput(head(StocksData))
structure(list(ACE = c(56.86, 56.82, 56.63, 56.39, 55.97, 55.23
), AMD = c(8.47, 8.77, 8.91, 8.69, 8.83, 9.19), AFL = c(51.83, 
50.88, 50.78, 50.5, 50.3, 49.65), APD = c(81.59, 80.38, 80.03, 
79.61, 79.76, 79.77), AA = c(15.12, 15.81, 15.85, 15.66, 15.71, 
15.78), ATI = c(53.54, 52.37, 52.53, 51.91, 51.32, 51.45), AGN = c(69.77, 
69.53, 69.69, 69.98, 68.99, 68.75), ALL = c(29.32, 29.03, 28.99, 
28.66, 28.47, 28.2), MO = c(20.09, 20, 20.07, 20.16, 20, 19.88
), AMZN = c(184.22, 185.01, 187.42, 185.86, 185.49, 184.68)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the following part , i am calculating the daily percentage changes of 10 shares :

```
perc_change <- (StocksData[-1, ] - StocksData[-nrow(StocksData), ])/StocksData[-nrow(StocksData), ] * 100
perc_change
```

Output :

```
#    ACE  AMD   AFL    APD    AA   ATI   AGN   ALL    MO  AMZN
#2 -0.07  3.5 -1.83 -1.483  4.56 -2.19 -0.34 -0.99 -0.45  0.43
#3 -0.33  1.6 -0.20 -0.435  0.25  0.31  0.23 -0.14  0.35  1.30
#4 -0.42 -2.5 -0.55 -0.525 -1.20 -1.18  0.42 -1.14  0.45 -0.83
#5 -0.74  1.6 -0.40  0.188  0.32 -1.14 -1.41 -0.66 -0.79 -0.20
#6 -1.32  4.1 -1.29  0.013  0.45  0.25 -0.35 -0.95 -0.60 -0.44
```

With the above code i find  the latest N rates of change (N should be in [1,10]).
I want to make **Logistic Regression Model in order to predict the change of the next day (N + 1), i.e., "increase" or "decrease".**

Firstly, i split the data into two chunks: training and testing set :
(NOTE: as `testset` i must take the last 40 sessions and as `trainset` the previous 85 sessions of the test set !)

```
trainset <- head(StocksData, 870)
testset <- tail(StocksData, 40)
```

Continued with the fitting of the model:

```
model <- glm(Here???,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=trainset)
```

**The problem iam facing is that i dont have understand and i dont know what to include in the `glm` function.** *I have study many models of logistic regression and i think that i havent in my data this object that i need to place there.*

Any help for this misunderstanding part of my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you shared, you need to predict an increment or decrease when new data arrives about the portfolio you mentioned. In that case, you need to define the target variable. We can do that computing the number of positive and negative changes. With that variables, we can create a target variable with 1 if positive is greater than negative (there will be an increment) and with 0 if opposite (there will not be an increment). Data shared is pretty small but I have sketched the code so that you can apply the training/test approach for the modeling. Here the code:

We will start from `perc_change` and compute the positive and negative variables:

```
#Build variables
#Store number of and positive negative changes
i <- names(perc_change)
perc_change$Neg <- apply(perc_change[,i],1,function(x) length(which(x<0)))
perc_change$Pos <- apply(perc_change[,i],1,function(x) length(which(x>0)))
```

Now, we create the target variable with a conditional:

```
#Build target variable
perc_change$Target <- ifelse(perc_change$Pos>perc_change$Neg,1,0)
```

We create a replicate for data and remove non necessary variables:

```
#Replicate data
perc_change2 <- perc_change
perc_change2$Neg <- NULL
perc_change2$Pos <- NULL
```

With `perc_change2` the input is ready and you should split into train/test data. I will not do that as data is too small. I will go directly to the model:

```
#Train the model, few data for train/test in example but you can adjust that
model <- glm(Target~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=perc_change2)
```

With that model, you know how to evaluate performance and other things. Please do not hesitate in telling me if more details are needed.

Comment: Firstly, thank you @Duck for your help nd your effort. I run your code and it works fine with me data ! I face some difficulties finding the predictive ability of the model and then the ROC curve. I dont know if its related with the below code , probably my mistake .

Comment: @ilaiaszarkHD Hi dear, I can not tell what is happening as I can not see your data but with the variables computed the rest can be a piece of cake. If you are still on trouble you can invite me to chat and I am glad to help you https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Of course i understand you. I will study again my code and your code and i will run again the whole process and then i will send you a message in a few hours later today in order to explain you my problem. Thanks again. @Duck

Comment: @ilaiaszarkHD Great! So feel free to send me a chat invite and I will be there. A pleasure

Comment: Honestly i cant find your profile in Stack Exchange @Duck, i try it a lot of times..

Comment: @ilaiaszarkHD Follow the answer of the link I shared with you, you have enough points an I have had chats with many people of 1 reputation. If you want to find my user click on users, and then look for the Duck in the first or second page. Glad to chat with you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225909/discussion-between-ilaias-zark-hd-and-duck).